# Displaying parts of an API Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api

So I'm working with an API for vehicles, and I am running into a wall and hoping to get some input from those with more experience with this... I'll start by showing an example of the data I get back from an API call.

```
Array
(
    [make] => Array
    (
        [id] => 200003644
        [name] => Chrysler
        [niceName] => chrysler
    )

[model] => Array
    (
        [id] => Chrysler_200
        [name] => 200
        [niceName] => 200
    )

[engine] => Array
    (
        [equipmentType] => ENGINE
        [availability] => USED
        [cylinder] => 6
        [size] => 3.6
        [configuration] => V
        [fuelType] => flex-fuel (unleaded/E85)
        [horsepower] => 295
        [type] => flex-fuel (FFV)
        [code] => ERB
        [rpm] => Array
            (
                [horsepower] => 6350
                [torque] => 4250
            )

        [valve] => Array
            (
                [gear] => double overhead camshaft
            )

    )

[transmission] => Array
    (
        [equipmentType] => TRANSMISSION
        [availability] => USED
        [transmissionType] => AUTOMATIC
    )

[drivenWheels] => front wheel drive
[numOfDoors] => 4
[options] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category] => Safety
                [options] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 200741607
                                [name] => SafetyTec
                                [description] => Adaptive Cruise Control with Stop & Go; Advanced Brake Assist; Automatic high beam control; Blind Spot and Cross Path Detection; Full Speed Forward Collision Warning Plus; Lane Departure Warning Plus; Parallel and Perpendicular Park Assist with Stop; Rain sensitive windshield wipers
                                [equipmentType] => OPTION
                                [availability] => All C/All C Platinum
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [category] => Package
                [options] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 200741480
                                [name] => Quick Order Package 26N (Fleet)
                                [description] => Vehicle with standard equipment
                                [equipmentType] => OPTION
                                [availability] => All C
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 200741610
                                [name] => Premium Group
                                [description] => 115V auxiliary power outlet; Exterior mirrors with memory; Heated 2 tone leather steering wheel; Luxury door trim panel; Premium leather trimmed ventilated front seats with leather seat cushion; Radio/driver seat/Climate control with memory; Real wood/bronze chrome interior accents
                                [equipmentType] => OPTION
                                [availability] => All C/All C Platinum
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 200741715
                                [name] => Premium Lighting Group
                                [description] => HID headlamps with LED daytime running lights; LED fog lamps
                                [equipmentType] => OPTION
                                [availability] => All S/All C
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 200741805
                                [name] => Navigation And Sound Group I
                                [description] => 506 watt amplifier; SiriusXM traffic with 5-year of included service; Travel Link Service with 5-year of included service; 9 amplified speakers with subwoofer; GPS navigation; HD radio; Uconnect 8.4AN AM/FM/SiriusXM/Hard disc drive/Bluetooth/Navigation
                                [equipmentType] => OPTION
                                [availability] => All C
                            )

                    )

            )
)
```

So if I have this data stored in a variable called $data for example, I can do something like this and it works:

```
foreach ($data['options'] as $options) {
    echo $options['category'];
}
```

That will return me "Safety", and "Package".

However, if I wanted to get the vehicle's make and I do something like this:

```
foreach ($data['make'] as $make) {
     echo $make['name'];
}
```

It just returns me the value : Cc  (Upper case C from the make name, and lowercase c from the make niceName).  Why is it doing this? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one `'make'`, so I think you just want this (no loop):

```
echo $data['make']['name'];
```

Comment: :-\ You're right, I over thought this hard. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Every element of `$data['make']` is a `string` (maybe `integer`), but **not** an `array` as every element of `$data['options']`. So, you can't use `[]` notation in case of `$data['make']`.

Just:

```
foreach ($data['make'] as $make) {
     echo $make;
}
```

will do what you need.

Comment: Already tried that as well. I get this as a result:  
200003644Chryslerchrysler

So it is combining the id, the name and the niceName - which I do not need all of that. To me, what you just said is exactly what I expect to write, to make it work. And it didn't.